# How to Render a table in template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

#### Models

```py
timetable_choices =(
    ('Monday','Monday'),
    ('Tuesday','Tuesday'),
    ('Wednesday','Wednesday'),
    ('Thursday','Thursday'),
    ('Friday','Friday'),
    ('Saturday','Saturday'),
)


class Timetable(models.Model):
    day = models.ForeignKey('Day',on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    start = models.IntegerField()
    end = models.IntegerField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=12)

class Day(models.Model):
    day = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=timetable_choices)
```

I have already populated the Day table and Timetable table.

#### Views

```py
class Timetabletemplate(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'timetable.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['timetable'] = Timetable.objects.all()
        context['monday'] = Timetable.objects.filter(day="Monday")
        return context
```

#### Template

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Monday</td>

    {% for item in monday %}
<td>{{item.subject}}</td>
      {% endfor %}

  </tr>
</table>
```

What I am trying to do is render subject in a cell.I have n subjects, number of subjects depend on how many subjects the user has added  . I want the subjects when day = Monday in the first row and similarly when day = Tuesday,wednesday in the respective rows below monday .

I am getting an error 
`invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Monday'` when I tried this code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
context['monday'] = Timetable.objects.filter(day__day="Monday")
```

as you are using `ForeignKey` to `Day` model, the days are save as `pk` and not the choice name